# I'm just learning laravel and I'm trying to implement a one to many relationship between a Book and a Review, but the seeding fails and idk why

Tags: php, one-to-many, data-migration, laravel-10, laravel-seeding

the Book model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function reviews(){
        // a book can have many reviews
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
        
        // i tried
            //return $this->hasMany(Review::class, 'book_id');
        //but it didn't solve the problem
    }
}
```

the Review model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function books(){
        // a review is tied to one book
        return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
        // I tried
            //return $this->belongsTo(Book::class,'book_id');
        //but it didn't work
    }
}
```

the migration file for the Book model

```
public function up() : void
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

the migration file of the Review model

```
public function up() : void
    {
        Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();


            $table->text('review');
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('rating');
            $table->timestamps();

            //?defining the foreign key
            // $table->unsignedBigInteger( 'book_id' );
            // $table->foreign( 'book_id' )
               ->references( 'id' )->on( 'books' )->onDelete( 'cascade' );

            //?a shorter syntax
            $table->foreignId('book_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        });
    }
```

the BookFactory file

```
public function definition() : array
    {
        return [
            'title'      => fake()->sentence(3),
            'author'     => fake()->name,
            'created_at' => fake()->dateTimeBetween('-2 years'),
            'updated_at' => fake()->dateTimeBetween('created_at', 'now')
        ];
    }
```

the ReviewFactory

```
class ReviewFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition() : array
    {
        return [
            'book_id'    => null,
            'review'     => fake()->paragraph,
            'rating'     => fake()->numberBetween(1, 5),
            'created_at' => fake()->dateTimeBetween('-2 years'),
            'updated_at' => fake()->dateTimeBetween('created_at', 'now')
        ];
    }


    //? Create state methods to create more diversity in the generated data
    public function good(){
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'rating' => fake() -> numberBetween(4,5)
            ];
        });
    }
    public function average(){
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'rating' => fake() -> numberBetween(2,5)
            ];
        });
    }
    public function bad(){
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'rating' => fake() -> numberBetween(1,3)
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

the DatabaseSeeder.php file

```
public function run() : void
    {
        Book::factory(34)->create()->each(function ($book) {
            $numReviews = random_int(5, 30);
            Review::factory()
                ->count($numReviews) //the number of the reviews generated
                ->good() // using the state method to define the 'rating'
                ->for($book) // associating the records to the current generated book
                ->create();
        });
        Book::factory(33)->create()->each(function ($book) {
            $numReviews = random_int(5, 30);
            Review::factory()
                ->count($numReviews)
                ->average()
                ->for($book)
                ->create();
        });
        Book::factory(33)->create()->each(function ($book) {
            $numReviews = random_int(5, 30);
            Review::factory()
                ->count($numReviews)
                ->bad()
                ->for($book)
                ->create();
        });
    }
```

the error message i get when I run "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed"

```
   INFO  Rolling back migrations.

  2023_08_17_222856_create_reviews_table ...................................... 18ms DONE
  2023_08_17_222848_create_books_table ......................................... 7ms DONE
  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table ........................ 8ms DONE
  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table ................................... 7ms DONE
  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_reset_tokens_table ......................... 7ms DONE
  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table ......................................... 7ms DONE


   INFO  Running migrations.

  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table ........................................ 33ms DONE
  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_reset_tokens_table ........................ 36ms DONE
  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table .................................. 24ms DONE
  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table ....................... 34ms DONE
  2023_08_17_222848_create_books_table ......................................... 9ms DONE
  2023_08_17_222856_create_reviews_table ...................................... 45ms DONE


   INFO  Seeding database.


   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'book_id' cannot be null (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `reviews` (`book_id`, `review`, `rating`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (?, Officiis consequatur temporibus maxime sequi laudantium et. Nam non voluptas est ea. Id fugit et amet deserunt ullam laborum eveniet. Harum eos ratione voluptate debitis qui sequi., 5, 2022-11-02 05:18:02, 2022-12-06 12:41:24))

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:795
    791▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    792▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    793▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    794▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 795▕             throw new QueryException(
    796▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    797▕             );
    798▕         }
    799▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:580
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'book_id' cannot be null")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:580
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

I was expecting to find a 100 books and between 5 to 30 reviews for each book seed to the database, but when I checked phpMyAdmin I found that only 34 books have been seed and that no reviews at all were seed, but I found that the foreign key column has been added to the reviews table.

Answer (score 0):

OK, some things I found.

1. In your Review Model the name of a belongs to function should be singular. So it's `book()` not `books()`.
2. You forgot to comment out the line `->references( 'id' )->on( 'books' )->onDelete( 'cascade' );` in your review migration file.
3. In your Book- and ReviewFactory you have `faker()->name` and `faker()->paragraph` which should be functions, so `faker()->name()` and `faker()->paragraph()`
4. In your Book- and ReviewFactory you have `fake()->dateTimeBetween('-2 years')`. I'm not 100% shure but i think it should took either 0 or 2 parameters, for example `fake()->dateTimeBetween('-2 years', 'now')`
5. ...and this is, where your error message comes from. In your ReviewFactory you have `'book_id' => null`. Just delete this line.

In your DatabaseSeeder your code could look like this:

```
public function run(): void
{
    $book = Book::factory(34)
        ->has(Review::factory()->count(random_int(5, 30)), 'reviews')
        ->create();
}
```

I would always recommend to do one thing at a time and regularly check if your code works.